# Making lstinline make line break at any character (letters, digits, ...)

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I have special data I want to include via `lstinline` into a floating text. The main problem is that the data does not contain certain characters you could define a line break on (like space, dot, dash, ... or if they have the sections between the dots are way too long).

So I would like to handle line break that way that it can make a line break at any character.

In the end what I want to avoid is that the text is truncated by the page size and that it is not printed on the right margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\lstset{breaklines=true}
\blindtext 
Some text 12345
\lstinline{23rewrgret54z54h54zu54u56kwfeewt43t34tzhhj56thu65i6767j67ki67k678k678kl78l789o67kjmgj56rrz756858u566j5r}
some more text.
\blindtext 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would something like https://ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit work or do you need some special features from listings like syntax highlighting?

Comment: listings isn't really meant for this. It wants to highlight keywords, that means it does lots of look head and collecting to grab the keywords, and this interferes with the idea to insert something arbitrary between each token. You can insert break points after chars with `literate={k}{k\-}1`, but generally I think some other command which can split chars is more suitable.